# Adding Telescope / Meteor App to existing Wordpress site

Tags: customization

I have an existing Wordpress website (www.mumbairunners.com). I have created a meteor app using Telescope (www.telescopeapp.org). I want to create a new page on my wordpress website and link it to the meteor app.

Note that the hosting of my website is with a third party and not with wordpress.com

How can I make this happen ?

Please help.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://www.telescopeapp.org/docs/)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could add a menu item to a nav menu linking to your meteor app, but considering that the app is a Node/JS application, not PHP, there's no way to directly integrate the two. You can't run Node JS in PHP, and you can't run PHP in Node JS. You'll have to duplicate your template so that your WordPress theme and your Telescope theme match

Answer (score 0):

Building on what [Tom J Nowell said in his comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183030/adding-telescope-meteor-app-to-existing-wordpress-site#comment267358_183030) you can't directly integrate it. I'd say your only (although hacky) way of achieving something close to this is a custom template with an iframe.

You just create a new page. Then you need a [Custom Page Template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template). You have two options, either a Custom Page Template or a [Specialized Page Template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Specialized_Page_Template).

Inside this template it depends if you want header, menu and footer of your site or you don't. Say you only want the app without any site navigation just put an iframe in this template and be done.

```
<iframe src="http://url-of-your-app.tld" />
```

You'll probably need some more CSS to make the iframe fullscreen but I think you get the general idea. Let me know if you need more detailed directions.

Comment: I think iframe is my best bet. I shall try this out and update you guys. Thanks for the help guys.